# Is it okay to ask my manager about the status of my regularization?

Tags: new-job, philippines

It has been over a month now since my trainee contract has ended. I still get paid('trainee salary' which is low) and still have no benefits (since I'm still not a regular employee). Problem is, I never heard anything from my company/manager after my contract has ended.

After 2 weeks of no update since my contract ended, I tried asking my manager politely regarding my employment status and what he just told me is that my employment status is in ***"For Regularization"***. This is my first job and I don't know much on how regularization works. Does regularization usually last more than a month? It's over a month now since I asked about my regularization status and I'm planning to ask our manager again about it. Is it okay to ask him again or will it sound rude now since I've already asked about it before.

**UPDATE 1/8/20**: Upon reading your answers, I tried messaging our manager yesterday(since I'm currently deployed somewhere else and can't talk to him directly). I asked politely regarding my employment status. ***Our manager just "seen" my message.*** I find it really upsetting since I did not get any clear response. What's more frustrating is the fact that I can see him online and chat in our department group. I don't know if he got mad at me for asking.

Comment: Does your company have an HR department? Maybe you should ask them as well.

Comment: What country? I've not come across the term 'for regularization' in the UK or USA.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk Yes we do. But in our case, our manager is the one who communicates with the HR regarding our employment status. That's why I plan to talk to our manager instead of our HR directly.

Comment: Stop allowing your mind to fill in the blanks. Many people simply don’t respond right way to queries like this with no malicious intent. People are people and if you feel the need to ask, just broach the topic. “What's more frustrating is the fact that I can see him online and chat in our department group.” That doesn’t mean he’s ignoring you.

Answer (score 4):

Yes it's OK, as it involves your pay.

If you only worked half a day every day, your boss wouldn't just mention it once and think it rude to remind you a week later that you were supposed to work all day.

They pay for your work, so the two are equally important.

Answer (score 3):

**It's not rude, rather it's very important that you talk about it and get it cleared ASAP.**

As per your statement, you currently have no work agreement, which is wrong from many aspects. I am not sure of the regularization process, but whatever it is, it most certainly does not require to leave an employee "hanging" with no clear employment status, or an employment without a contract / agreement. It may take it's own time, but that should be mentioned in the work agreement, just like the training or probation period.

Please talk to your manager again (and again if needed) to get the needful done to sign a new contract, with revised salary and benefits, as applicable.

Answer (score 0):

If there was an industrial accident, the court (depending on location) would apply their own contract so it is in the interests of both parties to get the contract sorted.

Comment: Is this answer possibly mis-placed?

Comment: @AdzzzUK no, I have not lost it.